# Trouble upgrading to Django 1.7.1

Tags: python, django

I thought I upgraded Django tonight by running:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade django==1.7.1
```

and I get this response from my shell:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: Django in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

So I assume that the upgrade happened successfully.  But when I run:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

I am told that the version is:

```
1.6.5
```

I want to be on 1.7.1 (I believe this is the most latest stable version).

Any advice?

Comment: You shouldn't be installing with sudo. Use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You might have two versions of Django installed. Delete them and then run:

```
sudo pip install django==1.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to remove your old version of django 1.6.5 with `sudo pip uninstall django` and reinstall it afterwards as you did. It's described this way in the [installation-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/install/#remove-any-old-versions-of-django), too.